# Show that $f$ is riemann integrable

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a bounded function on $[a,b]$. Suppose there is a sequence ${p_n}$ of partitions of $[a,b]$ for which $ \lim_{n \to \infty},[ U(f,P_n)-L(f,P_n) ]=0$. Show that f is Riemann integrable over $[a,b]$.

Proof: let $\epsilon>0$. since  $ \lim_{n \to \infty},[ U(f,P_n)-L(f,P_n) ]=0$.  then there exist $N_{\epsilon}$ such that if $n>N_{\epsilon}$ then $|U(f,P_n)-L(f,P_n) -0| = |U(f,P_n)-L(f,P_n) |<\epsilon$. Note that $U(f,P_n)> L(f,P_n)$ therefore i can say that $U(f,P_n)-L(f,P_n)<\epsilon$. But now i am stuck because to show that something is riemann integrable i have to show that the upper sum and the lower sum are equal to each other any idea thanks

Comment: Please include the precise definition or Riemann integrable you are using (including the definition of upper sum and lower sum you mention in your post).

Comment: I mean $U(f,P_n )$ and $L(f,P_n )$

Comment: The definition of Riemann integrability does not require $L(f, P_n) = U(f, P_n)$ as your last sentence seems to suggest.

Comment: yeah i thought that but i think i found a theorem that can help

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your definition of integrable is that $L(f) = U(f)$.  If $P$ is an arbitrary partition, then $U(f) \le U(f,P)$ and $L(f) \ge L(f,P)$.  Given $\epsilon > 0$ you can select $P_n$ so that $U(f,P_n) \le L(f,P_n) + \epsilon$ so that $$U(f) \le U(f,P_n) \le L(f,P_n) + \epsilon \le L(f) + \epsilon.$$ Now let $\epsilon \to 0^+$.

If your definition of Riemann integrable involves Riemann sums the answer is different.

Comment: no it does not involve riemann sums